# VS2017 with new getter/setter syntax: How to write multiple lines in the setter?/

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, VS2017. 
VS2017 has got new syntax for getter and setter. Now the property with getter setter looks like below:

```
public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
```

I have to write the below property. How can I write the setter with lambda expression set=> ?

```
public int EmployeeNumber
    {
        get => _employeeNumber;
        set { _employeeNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeNumber");}
    }
```

such as something like this:

```
public int EmployeeNumber
{
   get => _employeeNumber;
   set =>{ _employeeNumber = value;OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeNumber"); }
}
```

For the above setter, I get 3 errors:

```
CS1525: Invalid expression term {
CS1002: ; expected
CS1014: A get or set accessor expected
```

Comment: As an aside, this is a C# 6 feature ([Expression-Bodied Function Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)), not related to the .NET version you're targeting or the Visual Studio version you're using (directly).

Comment: The documentation says: "You can use an expression body definition whenever the logic for any supported member, such as a method or property, **consists of a single expression**" So it is meant to make things shorter to write if you have a single expression. If you have more than one expression, use the {...} syntax.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Expression-Bodied getters and setters are C# 7, not C# 6.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes it is. See "More expression bodied members" [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Comment: @yaakov Ahh. you're right, got confused there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, lets go over this again. You want to write

```
public int EmployeeNumber 
{
    set 
    { 
        _employeeNumber = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeNumber");
    } 
}
```

Like this:

```
public int EmployeeNumber 
{
    set => 
    { 
        _employeeNumber = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeNumber");
    } 
}
```

The question is *why*? The whole point about expression bodied function members is to make things more concise and readable avoiding curly braces, return keywords, etc.:

```
public int Foo => foo
```

Instead of,

```
public int Foo { return foo; }
```

What you are attempting to do doesn't make it more readable and adds two useless extra tokens. That seems like an awful bargain.

As a general rule, you shouldn't use (or can't use) the `=>` syntax when the code on the right side:

1. Doesn't return anything (throwing exceptions is the exception, pun intended)
2. Is made up of more than one expression.
3. Is there because of the side effects it produces.

Of course rule nº3 is mine alone, I'm not aware of any coding style recommendations on this matter but I tend to avoid this syntax unless I'm dealing with no side effects producing methods.

Comment: Personally I think this whole syntax is a big shoulder shrug... not sure why they bothered adding this to the language.  As witnessed by this question it can only serve to confuse people

Comment: @Mick I tend to disagree, if used well, it does declutter code quite a lot. I prefer `public override int GetHashCode() => X^Y;` over `public override int GetHashCode() { return X^Y; }` any time. Can we live without it? Well yes, but I find it rather convenient.

Comment: I think the use of => for expression bodied members is a poor choice. There's going to be a lot of average developers who confuse this with lambdas and think there's some connection between the two.  This isn't introducing a new construct, its creating a potentially confusing new syntax for existing constructs.  Each to their own, but as someone who has to deal with average developers, I don't see the value in using it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i don't understand your point.  We're having this discussion now, not two years ago.